# Retrieving data from a web site

Tags: php, curl

I have a web site which has profiles for users. There is another page that lists all the users and provides links to their profiles. I need to collect all the data for all the users at one place. The web site operates through a login mechanism and I have tried to access the pages via cURL but have not been successful.

What ways can be used to retrieve the data?

Comment: Give us an example of not working code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Curl's cookie jar feature to save the cookies that you get during login.  Once you have the cookies you're second curl call will work using the cookie jar cookies. There's sample code in the comments on the php cURL

This is a decent tutorial with info for curl cookie jar.

http://icfun.blogspot.com/2009/04/php-how-to-use-cookie-jar-with-curl.html